# How do I get a route in my code for my WebAPI application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I have declared this route in my Orders Controller, overriding the default /orders/{orderid} route:

```
[Route("api/properties/{propertyId}/orders/{orderId}")]
public string Get(int propertyId, int orderId)
```

I would like to add a hypertext link to this Order in my Model, but I can't figure out how to get the URL of the route back in code.  I have done it in my views using the Razor view engine, but not in code.

Any idea how I can generically set this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name your route and then use Url.Link method to generate link from the route.

For instance,

```
      [Route("api/properties/{propertyId}/orders/{orderId}", Name = "testRoute")]
        public string Get(int propertyId, int orderId)
        {
            string uri = Url.Link("testRoute", new { propertyId = propertyId, orderId = orderId });

            return uri;

        }
```